# how to simplify model function in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have created an universal model function to fetch data from Mysql. I can use this function for all select data.

```
//Controller

$where = array('user_id' => 1);
$data['all_rewards'] = $this->select->selectData('tbl_example1', $where, null, 'user_id', 10, 1);

//Model

public function selectData($table, $where, $group_by, $order_by, $limit, $start) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($table);
    if(!empty($where))
        $this->db->where($where);
    if(!empty($group_by))
         $this->db->group_by($group_by);
    if(!empty($order_by))
        $this->db->order_by($order_by, 'DESC');
    if(!empty($limit) or !empty($start))
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result_array() : 0 ;
}
```

The above code is working fine.

Just I want to know that is there any simplified method other than my function to select data from database. And whether my approach is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this approach will survive, once your application starts growing. Soon you will come across select queries, that can't be fulfilled by your universal function (for example what if you need to 'select like' or to select only certain fields as opposed to (*)).

It's in fact a broad question about how to create a good MVC architecture.

Slightly better approach would be instead of trying to write a single universal function that will cater for all possible select statements, try to write a shorthand functions for a typical, easy queries, like SelectAll or SelectOne or SelectRow.

In general the Model should implement a ways of accessing particular data or db table represented by the model in your system. If you look to generalize the queries, consider extending CodeIgniter query builder and use the extended capabilities in your model as you see fit.

Let's say for example, you need a shorthand for getting a single field from a table:

```
function selectOne($table, $field, $id){
    $this->db->select($field);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
}
```

This function call would be very readable and self-documenting:

```
selectOne('product', 'price', 5);
```

This way you can abstract many typical ways of getting data in your application.